# How Disable an option on Datalist

Tags: html

how can I disable an option in Datalist?

```html
<input type="hidden" name="Town_Group" id="frmTown_Group">
<input name="Town" id="frmTown" list="frmTown_List">
<datalist name="Town_List" id="frmTown_List">
<option value="London">London</option>
<option value="Zurich">Zurich</option>
<option value="|" disabled=true >Italian</option>
<option value="Turin">Turin</option>
<option value="Milan">Milan</option>
<option value="Rome">Rome</option>
<option value="Naples">Naples</option>
<option value="|" disabled=true >French</option>
<option value="Bordeaux">Bordeaux</option>
<option value="Lion">Lion</option>
<option value="Paris">Paris</option>
</datalist>
```

I tried with disabled, the effect was that the option has disappeared.

Thanks Giovanni Rossati

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 3):

In that case you can use readonly attribute like this, **I wouldn't recommend this**

```html
<input type="hidden" name="Town_Group" id="frmTown_Group" />
<input name="Town" id="frmTown" list="frmTown_List" />
<datalist name="Town_List" id="frmTown_List">
      <option value="London">London</option>
      <option value="Zurich">Zurich</option>
      <option value=" " readonly>Italian</option>
      <option value="Turin">Turin</option>
      <option value="Milan">Milan</option>
      <option value="Rome">Rome</option>
      <option value="Naples">Naples</option>
      <option value=" " readonly>French</option>
      <option value="Bordeaux">Bordeaux</option>
      <option value="Lion">Lion</option>
      <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
    </datalist>
```

This is the only way because

Datalist vs Select:

- I guess this is what you want, but there is no comparison. Datalist
  is different, Select is different.
- `datalist` is used for autopopulating results from the list, based on
  user input, while select doesn't do any magic, it just shows all
  options it has.
- so this makes clear that there shouldn't be any preselected value in
  `datalist` (as it is used to auto populate, on user interaction). thus
  it cant be readonly
- select on other hand is different, it can have a default value, thus
  it can be readonly.

And yes what you said: "If you desire readonly or disabled, then use a select tag", yes, according to me its true, coz you cant set anything as selected in `datalist`, but you can in select.